# Mapping relationship -- foreign key or mapping table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, oracle

Try to get some professional idea here about which choice is better when creating schema relationships

I roughly find an idea from this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5239/indexing-uniqueidentifier-foreign-key-or-intermediary-mapping-table) but still try to get more thinkings.

A simple scenario could be like this:

```
class <--> Student <--> Teacher <--> class
```

(Assume a teacher can teach multiple classes)
it is a normal scenario with `many-to-many` relationship in a round. And query can start from any peer to any direction. So what could be a better design?

I know in one to one relationship a mapping table is definitely a waste, but is the mapping table solution `ONLY` good for `many-to-many` relationship, like that post mentioned? If we want to extend the many to many relationship with directions. If the relationship is `one-direction` instead of `bidirectional`, could the answer be different?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you explain why you'd consider mapping tables?  Also, could you give examples of where you'd worry about the direction of the relationship?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some simple rules:

For a one-to-one relationship, a foreign key can be held in either of the tables involved in the relationship, referencing the other table.

For a one-to-many relationship, the table on the many side of the relationship should hold the foreign key.

For a many-to-many relationship, you can create an association table (mapping table in your terms), which is a third table that holds foreign keys to both of the tables involved in the many-to-many relationship.

For example, assume we have the tables `STUDENT`, `CLASS`, and `TEACHER`. Generally, there is a many-to-many relationship between `STUDENT` and `CLASS`, and a one-to-many from TEACHER to CLASS (assuming a class only has one teacher). So, these tables might look like:

```
STUDENT: STUDENT_ID, STUDENT_NAME, etc.
CLASS: CLASS_ID, TEACHER_ID (foreign key), CLASS_NAME, etc.
TEACHER: TEACHER_ID, NAME, etc.
STUDENT_CLASS (mapping table): STUDENT_ID (foreign key), CLASS_ID (foreign key), GRADE, etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a many-to-many relationship then, yes, you would need a mapping table.  There is really no other reasonable way to store information about many-to-many relationships in a relational database (there are, of course, many unreasonable ways to do so).

If you want the relationship to be unidirectional (which seems very odd-- I can't envision a situation where entity A would have a relationship with entity B where B would not have a relationship with A so I would tend to suspect that the data model was incorrect if you wanted to implement something like that), you would still use a mapping table.  You would probably add another column to the mapping table that stores the `DIRECTION` (i.e. either 'A -> B' or 'B -> A').